# Fundamental group of a modified annulus

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

> Let $A\subseteq C$ be the annulus given by $A=\left\{z|1\geq|z|\geq\frac12\right\}$. Define an equivalence relation on $A$ as follows: two different points $z, w$ are equivalent if $|z| = |w| = 1$ and $z = −w$ or if $|z| = |w| =\frac12$
>   and $z = −w$. Let X = $A/ ∼$. Compute $\pi_1(X)$.

I've tried to use Van-Kampen theorem, by defining $U=\left\{z|\frac34\ >|z|\geq\frac12\right\}$ and $V=\left\{z|1\geq|z|>\frac23\right\}$
Then  $\pi_1(U) \cong \mathbb{Z}$ $\cong$ $\pi_1(V)$ and same for the intersection.
Then I think that  $\pi_1(X)=\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}/\langle a,b|a^2=b^2\rangle$
Am I correct?

any help will be greatly appriciated

Comment: Seems like you have the right idea. To be more precise, you want to take $U$ and $V$ to be the images of the sets you wrote down under the quotient map. Then one can deform retract these spaces onto the circles where the identifications take place, and the inclusion maps of $\pi_1(U \cap V)$ into $\pi_1(U)$ and $\pi_1(V)$ are multiplication by $2.$ So $\pi_1(X)$ should be $\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}$ divided by the conjugate closure of $\{a^2b^{-2} \}.$ (Is the subgroup generated by that set is already normal?)

Comment: @A.P. $\langle a^2b^{-2} \rangle$ is the kernel of the natural map $\pi_1(X) \to \pi_1(U) * \pi_1(V)$, thus is normal in $\pi_1(X)$

Answer (score 2):

You have the right idea, but as AP says, you have to take the open cover $\{U, V\}$ given by the images of $\{z : 3/4 > |z| \geq 1/2\}$ and $\{z : 1 \geq |z| > 2/3\}$ under the quotient map.

In that case, $U$ and $V$ are both homotopy equivalent to $S^1$, and $U \cap V$ deformation retracts to $S^1$. The inclusion induced maps $\pi_1(U \cap V) \stackrel{\pi_1 i_U}{\longrightarrow} \pi_1(U)$ and $\pi_1(U \cap V) \stackrel{\pi_1 i_V}{\longrightarrow} \pi_1(V)$ multiplies the generator $\times 2$ (geometrically, push the circle in the intersection up towards any of the top or bottom until it wraps twice about itself)

Thus, by applying van Kampen theorem, we get $\pi_1(X) \cong \pi_1(U) * \pi_1(V)/\langle i_U i_V^{-1}\rangle$ which is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z*\Bbb Z/\langle a^2b^{-2}\rangle \cong \langle a,b | a^2 = b^2\rangle$.

---

On the other hand, a good thing to note will be that identifying the top and bottom circle in the cylinder (which is homeomorphic to an annulus) via $z \sim -z$ is the same as pasting two disks to the two circles via the attaching map $z \mapsto z^2$.

That said, $X$ is a sphere with two cross caps, which, by an appropriate cell decomposition, has $\pi_1 \cong \langle a, b | a^2b^2 = 1\rangle$ which is isomorphic to the group we've wrote down above by the transformation $b \mapsto b^{-1}$.